# Nutch can crawl all website.Is there any rule to crawl specific site.Does need permission before start crawling from specific site.?

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

Using crawler we can search any specific site but this will slow the bandwidth of that site.Is there any rule before crawl specific site or using nutch we can search any site without an issue.I would like  to create vertical search using Nutch.Can anyone help me out from this question on the basis of above question section?

If specific site have not allowed Nutch bot in robots.txt then how can search that site using Nutch?Do we need to take permission before.

Answer (score 0):

In Nutch you can configure how many concurrent requests you can send to a specific host.

You can override this property in your conf/nutch-site.xml file.
By default Nutch will only send a request every 5 seconds to a server.

```
<property>
  <name>fetcher.server.delay</name>
  <value>5.0</value>
  <description>The number of seconds the fetcher will delay between 
   successive requests to the same server.</description>
</property>
```

In the robots.txt file you configure the exclusions of the website for specific user agent strings, not the other way around. 
If the site owner has not specifically disabled site access to search engines, you can crawl it with Nutch.

e.g. Exclusion of all search bots:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /
```